# Vue js making server call using vue-resource

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-resource

I'm trying to figure out how to make the below server call using vue-resource. I not quite sure how to set the header and send data using Vue.$http.post

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: "http://url/",
type: "POST",
headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
},
contentType: "application/json",
data: JSON.stringify({
    "email": "foo",
    "password": "bar
})
```

})

Comment: How about actually [reading the documentation](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/http.md)?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just do this:

```js
Vue.http.post('http://dev-api.languagelink.com/api/auth/login', {
  email: 'foo@bar.com',
  password: 'foobar',
}).then(res => {
  // Handle success response
})
```

vue-resource will automatically set the `Content-Type` header and stringifies the payload as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
this.$http.post('/url', data, {
   headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
   }
}).then(res => {
//do the stuff
});
```